# C++/CLI StreamWriter cannot specify path

Tags: c++-cli

i' m trying to make loginapp in c++/cli with users data log. I would use fstream but it isnt possible in cli. So I use StreamWriter and i cant specify totally normal path `C:\log.txt` (also tried) `C:\\log.txt` And when i debug my programme i get error 'access is denied' but also i have this problem when i run it like an admin. However when I just specify it like a `log.txt` it works and the file is being maked in vs project folder and its not satisfying for me. I paste my code below.

```
        StreamWriter^ log = gcnew StreamWriter("C:\log.txt", true);
        log->WriteLine(newLogin);
        log->WriteLine(newPassword);
        log->Close();
        label7->Visible = true;
```

I also tried a method with `@` operator but it also doesnt work. Sorry for my english.

Comment: The backslash is a special character in strings. You need `"C:\\log.txt"` or you should look into `Path.Combine`.

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt mentioned but i also tried it and it didnt work

Comment: Ill try with path.combine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C:\ is a path with admin permissions required. Try launching Visual Studio as administrator or change your path to some other which does not need them.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation seems to say that the StreamWriter constructor will only accept a filename, not a full path: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19czdak8.aspx

The functionality that you want is available with another class, namely System.IO.File: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.7.1